# ¿Como calcular los minutos, horas y segundos que han transcurrido de una hora a otra con momentJs?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Hola tengo el siguiente problema quiero calcular los minutos que han trasncurrdo de una hora a otra, obtenidas con mommentJS tengo lo siguiente:
Aquí obtengo la hora inicial:

```
const startExamDate = moment().format('HH:mm'); // 17:20
```

Supongamos que ha pasado 2 horas y guardo este horario aquí:

```
const endExamDate = moment().format('HH:mm'); // 19:25
```

Quiero sacar la diferencia entre startExamDate  y endExamDate, estoy intentado lo siguiente:

```
1.- moment(endExamDate).diff(startExamDate));
2.- endExamDate.diff(startExamDate, 'minutes', true)
```

Ninguna de estas parace tener resultado de ante mano les agradezo sus respuestas y comentarios, gracias.

Comment: Mi recomendación es que no uses Moment.js, en su [propia página](https://momentjs.com/) te dicen que no lo uses y consideres [otras alternativas](https://medium.com/swlh/best-moment-js-alternatives-5dfa6861a1eb)

Comment: Excelente recomendación ya estoy investigando sobre el tema muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acuerdo a la documentacion de moment hay varios formatos para mostrar un diferencia entre dos fechas:

```
const now = moment(new Date()); // fecha de hoy 
const end = moment("2022-01-1"); // fecha 1 de Enero de 2022

const duration = moment.duration(now.diff(end));

console.log(duration.humanize()) // esto imprime "25 Days"
console.log(duration.asMinutes()) // la duracion en minutos "35981.7867"
```

Echale un ojo a la [documentacion de durations](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/)